# What's the reason of having prefix "re" in the word "republic"?

Tags: etymology

Does that mean there was an even earlier form of government called "public"?

Comment: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/republic

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The *re-* in *republic* is not the prefix but the stem of the Latin word *res*, meaning 'thing' or 'matter' (it is the source of our *real*, something which is 'thingish' or 'material', not just 'thinkish').

The *-public* part is an adjective (the source of our *public*)  deriving ultimately from *populus*, the 'people'.

So for the Romans the *respublica*, the *republic*, was the 'matter of the people', everything of public concern—the Roman state.

<sub>Source: Mrs. Williams' 7th grade Latin class, Auburn AL 1959-60.

Authority: Lewis and Short, [*A Latin Dictionary*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dres), s.v. **res**, II.K</sub>

Comment: Can you please site a source? Etymonline, maybe?

Comment: @kris: *Res publica* is surely General Reference.

Comment: @Kris Sure. Added.

Comment: This is absolutely the correct answer. (For proof see the title of Cicero's work of political philosophy: "De re publica") It also explains why "republic" is the opposite of "monarchy". In a monarch, the state is the property of the king. In a republic, the state is the property of the people.

Comment: Additional note: the _s_ from the Latin nominative is still there in some languages, particularly Balto-Slavic ones: Russian _республика_ (respublika), Belarusian _рэспубліка_ (respublika), Lithuanian/Turkmen/Azeri/many others _respublika_, etc. Esperanto has _respubliko_, too.

Comment: Whoa, another Auburn native? Very cool.

Comment: @guifa War eagle!

Comment: @shane Well, *some* of the people, at least. :)

Comment: The Q is GR anyway. An 'answer' other than what's available as GR may be more of an educated opinion. (Could be more 'correct,' though that's a different matter.)

Comment: @Kris I've hunted you up an Authority to corroborate my Source.

Comment: @Kris on this site, one should "cite" their sources with a citation rather than just "site" them which would locate them on a parcel on land. (Sorry common mistake that bugs me).

Comment: @AffableGeek: it is interesting to see though that Kris asked for a source to be _sited_ and indeed, StoneyB placed the source at a geographical location, as per Kris's request. The homophone confusion may not have been completely lost on others before you mentioned it :)